# RESTful web service consuming using POST

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am using SDF framework and java technologies like JAXB, extJS in the UI part.

I have the end points, now i need to consume this using RESTful web services by sending the input as xml and getting back the output as xml.

I am very new to RESTful web services.. please do not tell to ready the whole book about REST  :)  instead suggest me how it can achieved in SDF(Service Development Framework.

Thanks.

Comment: what framework at server side ??

Comment: I think it wont matter right.. as they already exposed their service as a webservice.

Comment: are you consuming from browser itself or via your mid-tier ??

Comment: i will consume it from browser

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) article and specially restful webservices and jax b ..Write a client to consume your service through java you can use Apache http client and parse your xml using jaxb